# fatal error: call to undefined excuteQuery() processmaker at class.pmScript.php(208)

Tags: php, mysql, rhel6, processmaker

[Error Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vpNw.png)

Hi,

Can someone help/guide me on error appear.
The error is undefined excuteQuery() function however i didn't found any script  call undefined **excuteQuery()**.

p/s : error appear when i did the next process.

[class.pmScript.php](http://pastebin.com/qELaiNXj)

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function excuteQuery() in /opt/processmaker/workflow/engine/classes/class.pmScript.php(208) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

## **Detail**

ProcessMaker Version : **ProcessMaker 2.8 Community**

Operating System : **RHEL 6**

Database : **MySQL**

Comment: Hi Akemi!, well now i'm working on ProcessMaker, too, did you already try the newest version of ProcessMaker??, now we already released some version in the SourceForge, we already have the 3.x version. If it continues replying can you attach some images about your configuration, please?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with the function.

Its **executeQuery** and not **excuteQuery**. You are missing an "**e**".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use below code to check either you have permission to execute queries or not.

```
$query = "SELECT USR_UID FROM USERS";
$result = executeQuery($query);
print_r($result);
```